# Property [species_code] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have A problem with this eloquent, I trying to combine this 3 table to display the data in one table on view pages. But it turns to the error . please help me.

did I do any error on the coding or table relation?

Models:

> TreeCategory Models

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\TreeScientific;

class TreeCategory extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [

    'id',
    'code',
    'category',

];

public function scientific()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\TreeScientific','tree_category_id');
}
}
```

> TreeScientific

namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\TreeCommon;

class TreeScientific extends Model
{


protected $fillable = [

    'tree_category_id',
    'species_code',
    'scientific_name',

];

public function common()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\TreeCommon','scientific_id');
}


}
```

> TreeCommons

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TreeCommon extends Model
{


protected $fillable = [

    'scientific_id',
    'common_name',

];


}
```

> Blade.php

```
 <tbody>
      @foreach ($category as $kategori)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$loop -> iteration}}</td>
        <td>{{$kategori -> code}}</td>
        <td>{{$kategori -> scientific -> species_code}}</td>
        <td>{{$kategori -> scientific -> scientific_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$kategori -> scientific -> common -> common_name}}</td>

      @endforeach
```

> Controller
>
> use App\TreeCategory;
>       use App\TreeScientific;
>       use App\TreeCommon;
>
> ```
> class PokokController extends Controller
> {
>     public function pokokIndex()
>     {
>       $category = TreeCategory::all();
>       $scientific = TreeScientific::all();
>       $common = TreeCommon::all();
>
>       return view('')->with('category',$category)-
>         >with('scientific',$scientific)->with('common',$common);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: put controller code that you set ```$category```

Comment: I have add my controller to the Question